# How to detect current CDK bootstrap version from the command line?

Tags: aws-cdk

Based on `cdk bootstrap --help` and [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/bootstrapping.html) I can't find a simple one-liner to detect the current bootstrap versions of an account. Even the `cdk bootstrap` command itself doesn't seem to report which version it is setting up, so I can't review old logs to figure out which version it's currently up to.

I'd rather not do a `cdk deploy` to check this, because that is pretty slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the version of the Bootstrap template is recorded in SSM Parameter Store under the name `/cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version`.

More generally, the name of the SSM parameter is `/cdk-bootstrap/{qualifier}/version`, with the default `qualifier` being `hnb659fds`. The qualifier is customizable by setting the `--qualifier` flag when calling `cdk bootstrap`.

So to find out the version of the `CDKToolkit` template that's currently deployed, you simply fetch the value of this parameter. If using the AWS CLI:

```bash
$> aws ssm get-parameter --name /cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version --query Parameter.Value

"14"
```

You can omit the `--query` flag to get the full information about the parameter, including the time it was last modified.

Comment: Fantastic, [incorporated](https://github.com/linz/geostore/pull/2190).